# Customizing Symfony2 forms

Tags: forms, symfony

I recently started using Symfony2 framework. 
I already apologize for any incorrect terminology I will be using.

I would like to customize how forms are presented in my application.

More specifically, in my Twig file I am rendering the entire form with

```
{{ form(forms) }}
```

I would like to customize the layout of the form. I know that each row of the form can be expanded as

```
{{ form_start(forms) }}

//...
<div>
    {{ form_label(forms.field) }}
    {{ form_errors(forms.field) }}
    {{ form_widget(forms.field) }}
</div>
//...

{{ form_end(forms) }}
```

With the form written in this format I could add the needed customization to the layout.

Here is the problem: my form does not have a pre-defined number of rows, but these depend on some values stored in the database. What I would like to do in my Twig is something like this

```
{{ form_start(forms) }}

{% for field in forms %}
<div>
    {{ form_label(forms.field) }}
    {{ form_errors(forms.field) }}
    {{ form_widget(forms.field) }}
</div>
{% endfor %}

{{ form_end(forms) }}
```

Unfortunately, this for loop does not work.
I also looked into ([How to Customize Form Rendering](http://symfony.com/doc/2.5/cookbook/form/form_customization.html)), but I think this does not suit my case (does it?).

Any suggestion?
Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to customize form_row method http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/form_customization.html#customizing-the-form-row

```
// my_form.html.twig
{% extends 'form_div_layout.html.twig' %}

{% block form_row %}
    <div>
        {{ form_label(form) }}
        {{ form_errors(form) }}
        {{ form_widget(form) }}
    </div>
{% endblock form_row %}

// view.html.twig
{% form_theme form 'my_form.html.twig' %}
{{ form_start(form) }}
```

Comment: Yes! You are right! Answer was just beneath my eyes...
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

As a more flexible solution, you can do what you want directly without changing the way all form rows on the form are themed together.

Assuming your main form contains a Collection (if not, let us now how it's done!) called `subforms` with a variable number of items in (each of which is another form), you can do something like this:

```
{{ form_start(forms) }}

{% for subform in forms.subforms %}
<div>
    {{ form_label(subform.fieldname) }}
    {{ form_errors(subform.fieldname) }}
    {{ form_widget(subform.fieldname) }}
</div>
{% endfor %}

{{ form_end(forms) }}
```